# How to apply 'And' condition inside an 'OR' condition in Laravel elequont

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

My Query is like

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE (active=1 AND linked_project_id IN (2,3) AND GLOBAL=1 OR (linked_project_id=2  AND active=1))
```

But I dont Know how to put 'linked_project_id=2  AND active=1' this inside AND with Laravel.
Here is my code for doing-

```
$activities=  Activitie::where('active','=',1)->whereIn('linked_project_id',array(2,3))->where('global','=','1')->orWhere('linked_project_id','='2)->where('active','=',1)->get();
```

but this is producing result like

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE (active=1 AND linked_project_id IN (2,3) AND GLOBAL=1 OR (linked_project_id=2 ) AND active=1)
```

Comment: can you please give an example of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres).

```
Model::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('a', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('b', '=', 1);
})->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('c', '=', 1)
          ->orWhere('d', '=', 1);
});
```